# Initialize helper class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, class, laravel-5

I wrote a simple helper class, placed it in `app\Helpers\MyHelper.php` and created an alias for it in the `app.php` configuration file:

```
    'MyHelper' => App\Helpers\MyHelper::class,
```

The problem is that, now I need to use the class constructor to initialize some default values in it. However, the `__construct` function will never get called. Obviously, since it never gets initialized.

The question is, how (or where) can I initialize the helper class properly, so it could initialize it's default values?

My first thought: `AppServiceProvider.php` file and the `boot()` function.

I have placed a `new MyHelper();` line there and it's working, however I'm wondering if this is a proper way doing it?

Comment: Could you show the context of your class to understand the problem properly?

Comment: @Gayan What do you mean? Just consider an usual class with the constructor in it. I want to make sure whether initializing it the way I described is an appropriate way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper class has static class so there no need to create instance of the class
for example

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class HelperFunction {

    public static function createGroup() {

}
```

so you can import class it in your controller using `use` keyword and access like

```
HelperFunction::createGroup();
```

Comment: I know about that. I need to initialize however, because the helper is loading a language file to array + it's setting different shared variables on initialize and it would be stupid to load those on each individual function call.

Comment: you can add that class in composer.json and then run composer dump autoload .so it will load automatically

Answer (score 0):

In general Services Providers are there for bootstrapping your application. The documentation doesn't say much about the `AppServiceProvider` but it seems to be there to bootstrap your app in general.

If you want to go the safe route you can create a new Service Provider by using `php artisan make:provider MyHelperServiceProvider` and add it in the `providers` array in your `config/app.php` file.

It looks identical to the `AppServiceProvider` but depending on your current code base it could be cleaner to put that helper into its own Service Provider.

I'm also just a beginner but to me both seem to be fine.

**update:** okay, found the important part in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/lifecycle

The last paragraph says:

> By default, the `AppServiceProvider` is fairly empty. This provider is a great place to add your application's own bootstrapping and service container bindings. Of course, for large applications, you may wish to create several service providers, each with a more granular type of bootstrapping.